# Eigenmode constraints on a complex wave field

Tags: fourier-analysis, helmholtz-equation

I'm studying the usual wave equation:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = 0$$

with complex field $\psi$, on a n-dimensional cube region of length $L$, which are $n-1$ spatial dimensions of length $L$, and one time dimension of duration $L/c$. Now i proceed to express the field in a Fourier expansion:

$$ \psi(x,y,..t) = \sum_{k, \omega} e^{I ( k_x x + k_y y + ... + \omega t)} \psi_{k,\omega}$$

If i do a cutoff in the expansion so that we only take $2M+1$ cells on each direction in k-space, that is, $- \frac{ \pi M }{L}, - \frac{ \pi (M-1) }{L}, .. 0 .. \frac{\pi M}{L}$ are the allowed values of the $k$ indices (and for $\omega$ too but with a $1/c$ factor somewhere) I am left with $(2M+1)^n$ complex fields to compute, because the field is not real, and the fourier expansion does not satisfy $\psi_{k_x, k_y, ...,\omega} = \psi_{-k_x, k_y, ..., \omega}^{*}$

When i apply the Helmoltz condition on the bulk of the cube, i am left with $(2M+1)^n$ (complex) conditions:

$$(-k_x^2 - k_y^2 - ... + \frac{\omega^2}{c^2} ) \psi_{k_x, k_y,...,\omega} = 0$$

Now, it seems that the Helmoltz equation imposes the same number of contraints as there are unknowns. My question: how can boundary conditions be imposed on this problem without producing an over-determined system